# How to handle floating point number

Tags: c#

I have following code

```
float m = vScrollBar1.Value;
float a = (100 - m);
textBox1.Text = a.ToString();

   float b = (a - 32);
   float c = (5 / 9);
   b = b * c;
   textBox2.Text = b.ToString();
```

when I scroll the scrollbar, value of textbox1 change gradually but textbox2 value always show zero. I used double also and still get show zero always. Someone please help me out here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is an often asked question. 5 / 9 is 0. You are performing integer math. Use 5f / 9f as a starter and see where it gets you.

Answer (score 2):

Because `(5 / 9)` is **integer division**.

Try `(5.0f / 9)` instead.

Comment: or you can also use just `5f`, just shorter a little bit